# How to avoid the black shell window after compiling my script with pyinstaller

Tags: python, shell, compilation, wxpython, pyinstaller

I am using wxpython to develop a GUI and I compiled it with pyinstaller. Everything works fine but there is always a black shell window pop up before it actually lunch the program. (Just like you use python instead of pythonw to run the script)

My question is, how to avoid that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From: http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/v2.0/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw#getting-started

> -w, --windowed, --noconsol
>   use a windowed subsystem executable, which on Windows does not open the console when the program is launched.