# How do I stop cmd from appearing when i run exe file (python 3, gui)

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x

So recently I made a script, and I also finished gui and managed to merge those two together. Now i wish when I start the exe file that cmd doesn't appear but instead only GUI? Any idea on how to manage this? So far my searching didn't yield any satisfying results. Some more info is: Python 3.5, using pyinstaller to convert to exe, Tkinter Gui, pycharm 5.0.1. Thanks!

Comment: I'm using pyinstaller, and I don't think py2exe will work with my python 3.5, but I'm new to this so maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I think I picked the wrong duplicate target. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584698/getting-rid-of-console-output-when-freezing-python-programs-using-pyinstaller) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6775040/compile-app-with-pyinstaller-but-do-not-launch-cmd-when-running-resulting-exe) will help you.

Comment: worked with adding --noconsole... python pyinstaller.py --noconsole -F myscript.py //  tyvm :)!

Answer (score 0):

Since your question mentions `.exe` executables, I'wll assume you work in the Windows environment.  Try using a `.pyw`extension instead of a `.py` extension for the python program.

Comment: I think I've tried that already and it was unsuccessful. I'll try again a bit later and will get back with result